# Stack Level Too Deep when deploying Rails 4.2 app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 4.2 application to Heroku but I'm getting a Stack Level Too Deep error during the asset precompile step:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/ext/fixnum.rb:4: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/builder-3.2.2/lib/builder/xchar.rb:111: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb:155: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb:155: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
       rake aborted!
       SystemStackError: stack level too deep
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_8529c6825cc1904afdc5ae19b4aaee28/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
```

That last line just repeats over and over. The assets compile cleanly on my dev machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just upgraded to a newer version of Rails (4.2.11) and everything worked.